# the number of generated threads

Tags: java, threadpool, servletcontextlistener

I want to make my listener to run muti-times, this my solution but i guess this will make a problem and number of threads in memory will be very large is it??

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                scheduleTime = Config.NILEDOX_INBOUND_AUTOIMPORT_ROTATE;

                if(scheduleTime>=1){

                    /** setup single thread to run background service every x minutes **/

                    service = new AutoInboundMailImportService();
                    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(service,1,1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);


            }
        }}, 120000, 60000);
```

any idea??

Comment: Why do you think there will be a lot of threads?

Comment: Why do you schedule twice? What's with the weird assignment and comparison of `scheduleTime`?

Comment: You should change `executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(service,1,1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);` to `executor.schedule(service,1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);`

Comment: i think that because the executor will call many times by the timer

Comment: executor.schedule(service,1,TimeUnit.MINUTES) is this will solve the problem i guess is the same just execution behavior changed

Comment: also i found that in the log file the thread pool size is rising up

Comment: You have defined the executor as `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();`, which means it will only use one single thread to handle all tasks, one by one, so there is only one thread created by executor.